# How are password protected Numbers files encrypted?

Tags: security, numbers, encryption

Does anybody know the security details behind password-protected spreadsheets in Numbers?

I've checked the documentation on Apple.com, but it's not exactly flush with technical details. From [Password-protect a Numbers spreadsheet on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/password-protect-a-spreadsheet-tan42502bf11/mac)

> Note: Adding a password to a spreadsheet encrypts the file

How actually is the encryption done (algorithms, key length etc) and what does get encrypted?

Comment: Similar question in superuser https://superuser.com/questions/1447200/pages-and-numbers-password-protect-feature-what-type-of-encryption. Without an answer :(

Comment: Apple documentation referenced in question contains the answer: “ Note: Adding a password to a spreadsheet encrypts the file.”

Comment: Still no specifics from what I can see.

Comment: There is support document [Data Protection Overview](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secf6276da8a/web) which have some specifics of data protection in macOS. This doesn't address the question directly but from there google-fu could help.

Comment: I'm sure Apple does not want to give any details _for security reasons._ Publishing the details of the encryption methods can assist bad actors with cracking the encryption.

Comment: @IconDaemon [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is a bad idea, for various reasons. In the specific case, I wouldn't trust an encryption if the vendor won't at least share the encryption method/algorithm used.

Comment: I agree with you somewhat, @nohillside, but in other ways I don't. State-level bad actors (Russia, China, Iran, N Korea, etc) actively attempt to breach encryption on many fronts - at the document level all the way up to the NSA. Although I'm generally an easy-going person, my guard goes up when questions at AD touch on encryption and bypassing MDM configs, for example.

Comment: @IconDaemon Especially if I wanted to hide information from state-level actors I would for sure use an encryption solution which is openly documented. Apple could use ROT13 for all we know, there have been times I could "break" that by just looking at the encrypted text. Obscurity hurts the public more than any bad actor, state-level or kid in the cellar.